# MATLAB: Perform callback on variable change?

Tags: matlab, callback

I am trying to build a GUI with several tabs, using `uitabpanel()` found at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/11546 . I would like to resize the GUI based on the currently opened tab; this is available with `uitabpanel.SelectedItem`.

Basically I would like to build a callback in order to monitor `uitabpanel.SelectedItem` - when this variable changes, the GUI window should resize appropriately. Generally speaking, I am looking for a way to monitor a variable and execute a callback when the variable changes value.

Is this possible? How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have a MATLAB in front of me right now, but if it is implemented as a property -- and as far as I can tell from a quick look at the code, it is -- you can use [addlistener](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/handle.addlistener.html) function and provide a callback function for it.

```
addlistener(hTab,'SelectedItem','PostSet',@(s,e)disp('SelectedItem changed'))
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I needed! It turns out that `SelectedItem` is not a property, but the underlying tab panels are just `uipanel` objects, and I can use what you propose by watching the `Visible` property for each tab. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with uitab from the file exchange. However, if it's build upon the built-in [uitab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/tab-panels-uitab-and-relatives/), then there should be a `selectionChangeCallback` or `selectionChangeFcn` property (depending on your Matlab version). Specify a function for this callback property, and you have a way to execute a function whenever the selection changes.

If that's not possible, the only other way to monitor a variable change (if you can't somehow use objects and set methods) is to use a [TIMER OBJECT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f9-38055.html) that periodically polls the value of the variable.

**EDIT** Since the FEX uitab is based on `uipanel`, the callback you're looking for is most likely [ButtonDownFcn](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uipanelproperties.html#bqxrv_b). Before you change it, make sure that it's not used by the uitab function, otherwise, you will want to edit that function.

Comment: I could definitely use OOP for this, but I feel like it's kind of like sandblasting a soup cracker - overkill for what I thought should be a fairly simple task. I guess it's not as simple as I thought.

I don't think uitabpanel() is based on uitab(), but I will definitely try out the callbacks you said. I don't think the former is based on the latter. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like uitabpanel() is based on uipanel(). I suppose I could switch to uitab(), but frankly uitabpanel() looks much prettier..

Comment: @strictlyrude27: Ah, ok, You may want to have a look at the `ButtonDownFcn` then, which is executed every time you click on the uipanel.

Comment: Thanks Jonas - I ended up trying that out. ButtonDownFcn sadly only works when you click *inside* the panel - clicking the tab itself doesn't execute the callback.

Perhaps going to `uitab` is the best bet? I don't like the timer object idea since I don't want to actively poll the variable.

Comment: There is a way to monitor a variable change, if it is a property, by using the [`addlistener`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/handle.addlistener.html) function. See my answer.